# Using newline in JFace ErrorDialog

Tags: java, jface

Has anybody managed to show a detail error message in the JFace ErrorDialog using newline (\n, \r) character?

I'm trying to display the StackTrace as a detail message, but it is only shown in one line

```
StringBuffer sbStackTrace = new StringBuffer();
for (StackTraceElement ste : throwable.getStackTrace()) {
  sbStackTrace.append(ste.toString()).append('\n');
}

final IStatus status = new Status(IStatus.ERROR, pluginId, statusMsg, new Throwable(sbStackTrace.toString(), throwable));
ErrorDialog dialog = new ErrorDialog(shell, "Error", customMessage, status, IStatus.OK | IStatus.INFO | IStatus.WARNING | IStatus.ERROR)
```

On open the ErrorDialog shows eveything I want, except that the detail message is not properly formatted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `ErrorDialog.populateList(List, IStatus, int, boolean)` method in the [source for ErrorDialog.java](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface/src/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/ErrorDialog.java?view=markup), it looks like the dialog only includes one `IStatus` per line, but if that `IStatus` has children, it will include them on subsequent lines.  So you'll need to either build a `MultiStatus` object or create your own implementation of `IStatus`.

Comment: That's it! Using one Status for every line works great.
Putting them together in a MultiStatus shows correctly the StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this working with just '\n' but I was also using:

`ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace( ex );`

[From Apache Commons-Lang.](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.html#getStackTrace%28java.lang.Throwable%29)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same it is also possible to build MultiStatus. MultiStatus can have next IStatus(es) as children and because ErrorDialog in detail area is showing one IStatus per line, you will get the same result.

Please see the trick in action in my other reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/9404081/915931

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Exception with a new that contains the stacktrace as message.

The code is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19703255/2064294