# How do I add new lines in the String passed to a java.util.function.Function? It ignores \n \t or System.lineSeparator()

Tags: java, function, swt, consumer

Trying to separate issue items with new lines to make it more readable to the user. I am using a `java.util.function`. Function to signal to the user that there is an issue. 
Function`<String, Boolean> issueCallback`

This is what I am trying to execute but all the issue items are printed on one long line that ignores `\n` `\t` or `System.lineSeparator()`. The line doesn't even wrap around. Please help.

```java
Consumer<FileIssue> fileIssueCallback = (issue -> {
    String msg = (issue.getException().isPresent() ? issue.getException().get().getMessage() : "No Exception " )
            + "- " + issue.getType() + "\n\n"+  issue.getPath() ;
    issueCallback.apply(msg);
});
```

[See snapshot thats displays the same run with the message msg displayed on both the console and GUI wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeGCs.png)

Comment: issueCallback is a Function<String, Boolean>

Comment: Not sure about your problem, but you should use the actual methods on `Optional` instead of using a ternary expression to retrieve its value. Like this: `issue.getException().map(Exception::getMessage).orElse("No Exception")`.

Comment: Printed where? I see no print statements.

Comment: What has this got to do with SWT?

Comment: I am feeding the message into a GUI textbox and its printing like this. I don't think its the GUI that's responsible for skipping the new line because the other text lines display new lines properly but what's odd is that a system.out.println shows the new lines properly but once it the same message is displayed on the GUI it ignores new lines. @greg-449

Comment: I will post pictures in a sec to explain what i mean @Andreas

Comment: Does this explain the situation a bit clearer?

Comment: What SWT controls are you using for the text? Some controls don't support line breaks or need to be told to do so.

Comment: I am using this method public static IStatus export(IProgressMonitor monitor, ExportProperties options)

Comment: // Errors are collected and shown as errors if the export fails, or as warning alongside the actual warnings if it does not.
List<String> issues = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

// Warnings collected that are displayed regardless of circumstance
List<String> warnings = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

Comment: Found a thread with someone that has the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694187/using-newline-in-jface-errordialog